# What's the format of this returned image data and how can I convert this image data to base64?

Tags: javascript, html, request

[image]

What is the format of this image data, like binary? How can I convert this image data to base 64? Thanks!

I wish to display this returned data and show it in the web browswer using the image tag .

Comment: Yes, that’s binary image data. Just use [`btoa`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/btoa) or the [`Blob` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob).

Answer (score 0):

That's png format you'd need to extract that data tag like for example `myobject.data` and convert it to base 64
Here's the docs on the base64 part https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64

But if you want to display it in the image tag I think you might want to just pass a link like `<img src="example.com/cat.png"/>`

Comment: base64Image = utf8_to_b64(data); // the function in the link you provided
img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + base64Image;
I did sth like this, img references to an image tag. But still not working. Do you know why?